# uitextfield is shown but the button is not shown

Tags: ios, uibutton

`UITextField` is shown but not the `UIButton`.
How can I show the button ??

```
UITextField *password = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30.0, 150, 300, 30.0)];
password.delegate = self;
[password setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
[password setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
password.placeholder = @"Password";
[password setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10]];
[self.view addSubview:password];
//button
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 200 , 50, 50)] ;
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(clicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeSystem];

 [self.view addSubview:button];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `BackgroundColor` and `TitleColor` of button:

```
[button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: THANKS a LOT THIS HELP

Answer (score 0):

you are intializing button two times.

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 200 , 50, 50)] ;

button = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeSystem];
```

Intialize system button and set its frame later.

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeSystem];
button.frame = CGRectMake(30, 200 , 50, 50);
```

Hope this will help.